# [Excel Source [37]] Error:SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

Hi Im facing the below error on my ssis package.

> [Excel Source [37]] Error: SSIS Error Code
>   DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  The
>   AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "Excel
>   Connection Manager 2" failed with error code 0xC0202009.

I even switch the Run64BitRuntime -from True to False - turning off the 64Bit for the solution but it didn't solve the issue.

My package is failing on the excel source. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Check the destination location exists, also check if you have access to location, and put full error message here, SSIS error messages are pretty misleading at times.

Comment: Expanding on @M.Ali's comment above: To succeed in this task, the account running the process must have at least read privileges on the folder containing the Excel spreadsheet, and on the spreadsheet itself. Also, the path to the SS needs to be correct from the perspective of the SQL Server - if the spreadsheet is on your local C:\Documents folder but your SQL Server is on another machine, the SQL Server needs access through a path from the SQL Server - something like \\MyMachine\C$\Documents\MyExcel.xlsx or \\MyMachine\DocShare\MyExcel.xlsx

Comment: Does the error occur on the development machine or on the server?

Comment: I've also noticed on my excel source 'Advanced editor' that the order of columns mapping does not match the order on the excel file, would that cause issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I just to turned out Run64BitRuntime  to false

Answer (score 0):

Close Visual Studio and reopen it; if turned `Run64BitRuntime` to `false` did not work. It worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not even look like an answer. Apart from being unreadable it mostly just states "it helped me to resolve" so it is saying thanks, which is not an answer.